# jQuery smooth scrolling goes a bit higher then i wanted to

Tags: jquery

i am using smooth scrolling in a one page website i build, and i am heaving a problem with the scrolling. The scrolling goes a bit below where i want it to go, and result in hiding the title of the section i am at.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function (event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {

      event.preventDefault();


      var hash = this.hash;


      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, function () {


        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End 
  });
})
```

Comment: Did you try substracting the height of the title element from $(hash).offset().top? e. g.  $(hash).offset().top - 100 or $(hash).offset().top - $('.title').height()

Comment: I would like to correct my question, I actually meant the opposite. The scroll goes a bit lower to where i wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve it was to place a value after:

$(hash).offset().top

to:

$(hash).offset().top -40

and it worked! it pushed the scroll a bit up, to the point i wanted it.